# Can't seem to get JQuery working (wordpress plugin)

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

Im trying to learn how to create plugins using Wordpress but I stumbled upon this problem:

> Whenever I'm trying to run JQuery I get undefined error's and such...

I tried different things I found on the internet like deregister/register/enqueue but nothing seems to work.

The goal is to fill a textarea in the plugin settings page without reloading/saving the page to create a live preview.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
class plugin 
{
  public function __construct()
  { 
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "jquery_enqueue");
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'plugin_page' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
  }

  public function jquery_enqueue() 
  {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  }

  public function plugin_page()
  {
    add_menu_page(
        '...',
        '...',
        '...',
        '...',
         array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
    );
   }

public function create_admin_page()
    {
        // Set class property
        $this->options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Test</h2>           
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( '...' );   
                do_settings_sections( '...' );
            ?>
            <script>                
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                    $( "#my_option_name" ).change(function() {
                        $.post( 
                          'classes/dummy.class.php'
                        ).success(function(x){
                            json = $.parseJSON(x);
                            $('textarea').text(json);
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
            </form>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
        <?php
    }}
```

I left some code out and only included the important parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common question. It plagued me when I first started because it doesn't make any sense and it is hard to search for until you *know*. The problem is that WordPress bundles a version of jQuery that is set to noConflict mode. Therefore, to run scripts you must use [noConflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

**Update**

1. There's no need to load a different version of jQuery. It just complicates things. Let, WordPress load it's own version. Delete your `jquery_enqueue()` method.
2. Next adjust your `create_admin_page()` to not print the script directly. What I think is happening is that `add_menu_page()` runs before `wp_enqueue_scripts` and so jQuery isn't available yet. Hence, error. Instead of printing the scripts, you can print them in the footer by adding a new function to the `admin_print_footer_scripts` hook.

So modified, your `create_admin_page()` would now look like this:

```
public function create_admin_page()
    {
        // Set class property
        $this->options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
        add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', array( $this, 'footer_scripts' ) );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Test</h2>           
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( '...' );   
                do_settings_sections( '...' );
            ?>
            </form>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
```

With your new function being:

```
public function footer_scripts()
    { ?>
            <script>                
                jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
                    $( "#my_option_name" ).change(function() {
                        $.post( 
                          'classes/dummy.class.php'
                        ).success(function(x){
                            json = $.parseJSON(x);
                            $('textarea').text(json);
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but without any luck. Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined

Comment: I would also advise not loading google's jquery. And I would load the script in the footer to be sure that jquery has already loaded. I'll edit here in a second.

Comment: I just replaced my code to what you wrote and fiddled some with it but it seems like whatever I do JQuery just doesn't want to load :/

Comment: You can always keep `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` but jQuery should load by default in the admin.

Comment: Got it to work forgot to remove the old jquery script, so when I was inspecting the browser it would give errors. It seemed like placing the script in the footer worked! thanks

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it working. Had a typo or 2 that I just fixed and was having trouble getting things to run locally for a test.